# Multi-line NSTextField not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextfield, autolayout

I have been trying to get a multi-line `NSTextField` to lay out automatically using `preferredMaxLayoutWidth`. I can’t figure out why this doesn’t work.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let textField = NSTextField()
      textField.cell!.usesSingleLineMode = false
      textField.cell!.wraps = true
      textField.cell!.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
      view.addSubview(textField)

      textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
         textField.topAnchor.constraintEqual(to: view.topAnchor),
         textField.leadingAnchor.constraintEqual(to: view.leadingAnchor),
         textField.widthAnchor.constraintEqual(toConstant: 20)
      ])
      textField.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 20
      textField.stringValue = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

      view.needsLayout = true
      view.layoutSubtreeIfNeeded()
      print("Intrinsic content size: \(textField.intrinsicContentSize)")
      print("Fitting size: \(textField.fittingSize)")
   }
}
```

This prints:

> Intrinsic content size: (-1.0, 21.0)
>
> Fitting size: (20.0, 21.0)

(21.0 is the size for a single line.)

Comment: What is not working? It looks like you've got the width set to show only one character per line.

Comment: @l'L'l The width is constrained to 20 points. I expect `NSTextField` to return a height that is big enough to accommodate all the text.

Comment: So why not use a constraint for `heightAnchor` also?

Comment: @l'L'l The text will be dynamically updated. I want to use `NSTextField`’s supposed abilities to automatically size itself correctly to fit all the text.

Comment: I’ve done the same via Storyboard (created textfield + 3 constraints) and see no problems, everything is resizing. Try to click «+» button to change text. Link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42855950/test.zip

Comment: @Vasily Thanks for the test project! I have found the difference between our two examples. My text field is editable whereas yours is not. Are you able to get multi-line layout to work with an editable text field?

Comment: @fumoboy007 try setting the text before setting the preferredMaxLayoutWidth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. So it turns out that when an `NSTextField` is in edit mode, a secret `NSTextView` (aka the “field editor”) takes over for the editing portion. Text changes are not synced back to the text field until editing has ended. This explains why my sample code only works in non-edit mode.

You can force the sync to occur by accessing the `NSTextField.stringValue` property. This is what I’ve done in a `NSTextField` subclass. I also provided my own implementation of `intrinsicContentSize` because Apple’s implementation doesn’t work in edit mode and is buggy in non-edit mode.

Comment: Thank you. My first foray into macOS development after years in iOS and I was embedding an `NSTextField` in an `NSViewRepresentable` and could not get the text to wrap until I overrode `intrinsicContentSize` and used the string `boundingRect(with:options:)` to calculate the size based on the enclosing view's bounds width.

Comment: Hi @fumoboy007, my comment is a few years late, but I am trying to do exactly the same thing but can't seem to get it to work correctly. Do you have any code that you can share? (will of course add attribution if I should use it). Thanks

Comment: @cgiacomi I ended up creating an `NSTextView` subclass that implements `intrinsicContentSize`. You can find it here: https://github.com/fumoboy007/ModernAppKit.

Answer (score 14):

There is an another solution for making the **NSTextField** multiline with using auto constraints and Interface Builder.

- Choose `Wraps` from **Layout**
- Choose `Character Wrap` from **Line Break option**
- Uses **Single Line Mode** must be `unchecked`

And add below sample constraints

- Trailing Space
- Leading Space
- Bottom Space
- Top Space

with the constants that you want. And don't add any specific height constraint.

Below some screenshots which might be helpful.

[image: Constraints]

[image: NSTextField Settings]

Comment: Worked under macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) with Xcode 10.0

Comment: If you are creating a text field programmatically, using this method: `let multiline: NSTextField = .init(wrappingLabelWithString: "")`

Comment: `Word Wrap` works just as good.

Answer (score 0):

The most important that you have to take in account is **Horizontal Compression Resistance Priority**, understanding compressions of the siblings you need to decrease your `NSTextField` compression value. For example, you can find out starting from the low number (250).

[image]